# Installing Canon Color imageCLASS MF8380Cdw Drivers in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I am trying to install the drivers for a Canon Color imageCLASS MF8380Cdw in a 64-bit installation of Ubuntu 12.10. Since Ubuntu did not contain the drivers, I needed to download the drivers for this printer from Canon's website. Since it only contained 64-bit drivers for an RPM-based distribution of Linux, I needed to use Alien to convert the packages to the .deb format before installing them. However, I  am not sure how to proceed from here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just setup this exact printer on 2 Ubuntu 64-bit 12.04 desktops. Here's the documentation that I wrote, hope this also works on 12.10.

1. Go to the below link and download the Linux driver in `~/Downloads`
   http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/printers_multifunction/color_laser_multifunction/color_imageclass_mf8380cdw#DriversAndSoftware
2. Untar the tar.gz file downloaded at ~/Downloads/Linux_UFRII_PrinterDriver_V250_us_EN.tar.gz
3. Assuming that a 64 bit machine is being used, `cd` to `~/Downloads/Linux_UFRII_PrinterDriver_V250_us_EN/64-bit_Driver/RPM`.
4. Create a symbolic link for 64-bit drivers:

   ```
   ln -s /usr/lib /usr/lib64
   ```

   (NOTE: There may be an existing `lib64` directory there already and this will prevent the symbolic link from working correctly. Backup/move the directory to an alternate location before creating the symbolic link)
5. Install alien (if needed):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install alien dpkg-dev debhelper build-essential
   ```
6. Convert the RPM files to ".deb"

   ```
   sudo alien -k -c cndrvcups-common-us-2.50-1.x86_64.rpm
   sudo alien -k -c cndrvcupsuf2us-2.50-1.x86_64.rpm
   ```
7. Install drivers

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i cndrvcups-common-us-2.50-1.x86_64.deb
   sudo dpkg -i cndrvcupsuf2us-2.50-1.x86_64.deb
   ```
8. Go to System Settings -> Printing and remove the Canon printer (if it's there)
9. Click on Add and expand Network Printer. Select Canon MF8300C (IP_ADDRESS). Click on Forward and then Apply. Click Cancel on the test page screen.
10. Right-click the new Canon printer -> Properties.
11. Where is shows 'Make and Model' press 'Change'
12. Select 'Provide PPD file'
13. Navigate to `/etc/cups/ppd/Canon-MF8300C-UFRII-LT.ppd` and press Open
14. Select 'Use the new PPD as is' -> Apply
15. Restart the cups service `/etc/init.d/cups restart`
16. Test the printer.

Comment: I actually tried this again in 14.04 (Canon now provides its own separate .deb files, so using Alien is no longer necessary), and the PPD file I'm supposed to select doesn't exist after I install the drivers and try to set up the printer. Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I've used this post more times than I can count. But good news, this has become much, much simpler (at least with Ubuntu 16.04 and Canon's 3.31 driver package).

Instructions:

1. Download driver package from [here on the Canon website](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/support-laser-printers-imageclass/color-imageclass-mf8380cdw?tab=drivers_downloads)
2. Extract the package:

   ````
   cd ~/Downloads
   tar -xvzf linux-UFRII-drv-v331-usen.tar.gz```
   ````
3. `cd` to the new package directory and run `install.sh`

   ```
   cd linux-UFRII-drv-v331-usen
   ./install.sh
   ```
4. Install your printer using steps borrowed from [Earl's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/265611/527764):

   - Go to **System Settings > Printing** and remove the Canon printer (if it's there)
   - Click on Add and expand Network Printer.
   - Select Canon MF8300C (IP_ADDRESS).
   - Click on Forward and then Apply.
   - Try to print a test page.

Comment: FYI - if you have rpm installed, install.sh will detect the system as rpm. If you encounter this, do `sudo apt remove rpm` to get the install script working. This will remove alien and rpm, so  take note of packages being removed so you can add them back afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Earl's answer, I managed to install the driver on my 14.04.

- In his step 1, the [link](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/printers_multifunction/color_laser_multifunction/color_imageclass_mf8380cdw#DriversAndSoftware) might be obsolete so that it redirects somewhere generic. However, on the redirected site, go to [Drivers & Downloads](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support) and typing in specific product id (in my case `Color imageCLASS MF8380Cdw` (that was nicely auto-suggested after typing `MF8380Cdw`)). There I saw [Drivers](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/support-laser-printers-imageclass/color-imageclass-mf8380cdw?tab=drivers#Z7_MQH8HIC0L88RB0AMD0F1Q42K25) tab where I found `Linux_UFRII_PrinterDriver_V320_us_EN.tar.gz` file.
- The tarball above already includes `deb`, so the rpm conversion in @Earl's post wasn't even needed for me.
- After installing via `deb` I needed to reboot the OS.

This may work for other Canon's printer versions. HTH.