# No PPD file while trying to install Canon imageClass MF8380 cdw

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I am trying to install driver for Canon imageClass mf8380 cdw using these instructions:

[Installing Canon Color imageCLASS MF8380Cdw Drivers in Ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251015/installing-canon-color-imageclass-mf8380cdw-drivers-in-ubuntu-12-10)

Everything goes fine until I have to provide a PPD file. The directory `/etc/cups/ppd` is empty and I am unable to find the PPD file anywhere.

Is there an alternate way of installing this driver or does anyone know where I can find the PPD file?

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution. With Ubuntu, unlike Debian (which I used previously) the driver provided by Canon actually works. When I installed it, it did not configure fully because it had a dependency on a missing package. I installed the package using `sudo apt-get install` and everything worked.

---

**Editor's Note:**

A dependency problem of missing package generally can be fixed with this command.

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

These problems mostly occur when a package is installed via `dpkg -i` command

Comment: What was the missing package?