# Install Canon printer lbp6030w

Tags: 14.04, drivers, printing, canon

I have been trying to install Canon Printer LBP6030w. I downloaded the driver, tried the generic driver, tried Synaptic package manager, downloaded all the updates from Canon, but none of these works.

Any ideas how to install and make it work on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS? Thanks for your help and advice.

Comment: Is there any specific error message that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

First cd into the 64-bit/debian folder

then:

Install both drivers using:

```
dpkg -i cndrvcups-common_3.30-1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i cndrvcups-ufr2lt-us_1.20-1_amd64
```

Now install these dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2:i386
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62:i386
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
sudo apt-get install libstdc++5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
sudo restart cups
```

You may need to also follow the process found here:

[Installing Canon Color imageCLASS MF8380Cdw Drivers in Ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251015/installing-canon-color-imageclass-mf8380cdw-drivers-in-ubuntu-12-10)

If all this still isn't working, remember to restart your computer and the printer. Simply restarting cups didn't work for me.

Source:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2259195